# A question about sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The sequence $b_{n}$ decrease to $0$, if the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_{n}b_{n}}$ converges, try to prove $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(a_{1}+a_{2}+...+a_{n})b_{n}=0$$
I came up with a complicated solution: let $d_{n}=\frac{1}{b_{n}}$,  $c_{n}={a_{n}}{b_{n}}$, then positive
sequence $d_{n}$ increases to $+\infty$, and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{c_{n}}$ converges. We just need to prove $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}{\frac{c_{1}d_{1}+c_{2}d_{2}+...+c_{n}d_{n}}{d_{n}}=0}$$ then use Abel's summation formul，we have $$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}{c_{k}d_{k}}}{d_{n}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}C_{k}\frac{d_{k}-d_{k+1}}{d_{n}}+C_{n}$$ here $C_{k}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}c_{i}$. Let C=$\lim_{n\to+\infty}C_{n}$, for $d_{n}$ increases to $+\infty$, it is not difficult to prove $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}C_{k}\frac{d_{k+1}-d_{k}}{d_{n}}=C$$
So we got the conclusion. I wonder if there is a simpler solution, for example, directly estimate $$(a_{1}+a_{2}+...+a_{n})b_{n}=0$$ for $n\to+\infty$ and get the conclusion.

Comment: is the question "Given the sequence $b_n$ decreases to $0$ AND the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n$ converges, prove $\lim_{n\to+\infty}(a_{1}+a_{2}+...+a_{n})b_{n}=0$"?

Comment: yes, the question is  what you said.

Comment: @uniether In the case where $a_n= 1$, then it is exactly Abel's (or Pringsheim's) theorem. Maybe you can adapt the proof to your general situation.